# sharing tkinter app and using my machine as MySQL server?

Tags: python, mysql, database, tkinter

Hi I have created a tkinter app that uses MySQL database but I have two questions:

1. when I will share my app with others, will they be able to use MySQL database that I have in my computer? If not, what should I need to change in my code?
2. after I transform the app to .exe by using pyinstaller, then why I can not send it to others people by gmail?

To connect to my database I used this:

```
    import mysql.connector
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="localhost",
                username = myusername,
                password=mypassword,
                database = "mydatabase"
                )
```

Thank you so much for any help or answer.

Comment: Since you use `host="localhost"`, then if your app is running in other machine, your app is trying to connect MySQL server at local machine.  You should either use a configuration file or environment variable to store the `host` information, then your app should read this information on application start up.  Also your machine should be accessible from other machine running your app.

Comment: can't send executables using gmail for security reasons, for example it might be malware, You will need to either compress that file or use cloud storage servieces

Comment: @acw1668  your answer is exactly what i want but i do not understand what you mean could you please explain  in detail ? or write some code .